# Openmpi: Parallel I/O for unknown non-continuous data

Tags: io, mpi

According to the official document, we cam simply use collective I/O to boost performance. For example, I can use n processes to read the same file with different offsets as the following program.

```
MPI_File fh;
MPI_Status status;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);

bufsize = FILESIZE/nprocs;
buf = (int*) malloc(bufsize);
nints = bufsize / sizeof(int);

MPI_FILE_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "data.txt", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
MPI_FILE_seek(fh, rank*bufsize, MPI_SEEK_SET);
MPI_FILE_read(fh, buf, nints, MPI_INT, &status);
MPI_FILE_close(&fh);
```

However, my question is how I can deal with unknown non-continuous. For example, I have a table of size m by n. For each time, I would like to read one column from file and compute some statistics. I will decide whether I need to store it on RAM or not. In that case, I can filter some data to save RAM. Originally, I use c++ to implement this by reading one column each time. But I want to improve the performance by using multiple processes.

Comment: `MPI_File_read()` is **not** a collective subroutine.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Sorry for my misunderstanding. So how can I solve this problem properly?

Comment: a column is non contiguous but regular. using a derived datatype and `MPI_File_set_view()` will do the trick.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet But before I read the data into RAM, we do not know whether we need this column.

Comment: so you always need this column, problem solved! If not, I will have to see some more code to understand your intent and advise.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Of course not. Each time I read one column and I compute some statistics to decide whether I need to store it. If it is under the threshold, I can discard it and then read next column.